# Must the surface of all standing water have a certain degree of convexity (every part must be an arc of a circle)?

Tags: geography, earth

According to the [Flat Earth Society](https://wiki.tfes.org/Experimental_Evidence), the Bishop Experiment demonstrates that it is possible to see Lighthouse Beach from Lovers Point and vice versa on a very clear and chilly day.

[image: A map of Monterey Bay, indicating the distance between Lovers Point and Lighthouse State beaches]

So:

> **IF the earth is a globe, and is 24,900 English statute miles in circumference, the surface of all standing water must have a certain degree of convexity**--every part must be an arc of a circle. From the summit of any such arc there will exist a curvature or declination of 8 inches over the first statute mile. Over two miles the fall will be 32 inches; by the end of the third mile, 72 inches, or 6 feet, as shown in this [chart](http://www.sacred-texts.com/earth/za/za05.htm).
>
> [image: EXPERIMENTS DEMONSTRATING THE TRUE FORM OF STANDING WATER, AND PROVING THE EARTH TO BE A PLANE]
>
> Correcting for the height of the observer of about 20 inches, when looking at the opposite beach over 23 miles away there should be a bulge of water obscuring objects up to 300 feet above the far beach. There isn't. Even accounting for refraction, the amount hidden should be around 260 feet - seeing down to the shoreline should be impossible

---

I'm aware of [Bedford Level experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedford_Level_experiment), which states:

> Atmospheric refraction causing an object below the horizon to be visible.

however the above experiment already takes into the account atmospheric refraction.

---

There was a similar [experiment done using a laser test at Lover's Point CA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6G4ubiFTgs) which claims:

> The complete video as taken from Lover's Point, Pacific Grove, CA. to Sand City, CA.
>
> Distance is 4.07 miles and should show an Earth curvature of 10 feet. With a camera at 30'' and 3 foot waves, the laser is still seen at below 6'' from 4 miles away.

Here is another [laser test](https://youtu.be/bwCRej0BoA4?t=440) over 7.5-8 mile distance on a frozen lake.

---

And here is another [mirror test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNgE0hU1J7w), shore to shore, over a distance of 13.23 miles, where, according to the [Earth's Curve calculator at metabunk.org](https://www.metabunk.org/curve/), the destination point should not be visible, even after taking into account a standard atmospheric refraction.

[image: Earth's Curve Horizon, Bulge, Drop, and Hidden Calculator]

```
Distance = 13.23 Miles (69854.4 Feet), View Height = 3 Feet (36 Inches) Radius = 3959 Miles (20903520 Feet)

Results ignoring refraction
Horizon = 2.12 Miles (11199.16 Feet)
Bulge = 29.18 Feet (350.15 Inches)
Drop = 116.72 Feet (1400.62 Inches)
Hidden= 82.29 Feet (987.52 Inches)
Horizon Dip = 0.031 Degrees, (0.0005 Radians)

With Standard Refraction 7/6*r, radius = 4618.83 Miles (24387440 Feet)
Refracted Horizon = 2.29 Miles (12096.47 Feet)
Refracted Drop= 100.04 Feet (1200.53 Inches)
Refracted Hidden= 68.4 Feet (820.74 Inches)
Refracted Dip = 0.028 Degrees, (0.0005 Radians)

Tilt Angle = 0.191 Degrees, (0.0033 Radians)

Horizon Curve Fraction = 0.00007
Horizon Curve Pixels = 0.23
Horizon Curve Angle v1= 0.00475
Horizon Curve Angle v2 = 0.00475
```

---

Based on the above experiments, should the surface of all standing water have a certain degree of convexity? If so, why is the point below the horizon still visible over the distance of 13-23 miles?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86099/discussion-on-question-by-kenorb-does-the-bishop-experiment-contradict-that-the).

Answer (score 10):

The calculations leave out important factors as to why you can still see things lower than 300 feet.

This is a replication of the [Bedford Level experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedford_Level_experiment)

It's a [well known](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=m9BM6DzFGGwC&pg=PT100&dq=Bedford+Level+experiment&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4i4Sz8ufeAhVKD8AKHUtIC9AQ6AEIRDAE#v=onepage&q=Bedford%20Level%20experiment&f=false), [classic experiment](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bi1bAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) done [many times](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZzDHPKxDkAwC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) that is in no way shape or form "theoretical"

[image: 9.7 km of water]

If light traveling through the earths atmosphere actually moved in a perfectly straight line then you would be unable to see things because of the bulge of the earth.

[image]

It's a result of [atmospheric optics](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/courses/m309-03a/m309-projects/grant/atmoptics.html) that allow us to see objects that would otherwise be over the horizon, there is a curve but our line of sight gets curved too.

[image]

## An explanation of the phenomenon, for the sake of readers, provided for clarity sake:

We've probably all seen mirages

[image]

when you have a ***hot*** surface the light is refracted from above so from your point of view you see a blue mirage on the ground.

[image]

That works the other way round over a ***cold*** surface.
[image]

Hence why the author specifically mentions looking on a **chilly** day.

As explained in the linked wiki article on the Bedford Level experiment, placing the camera **higher** reduces the effects of atmospheric refraction due to the cold water and allows you to see the "hump" of the curve of the earth.

Comment: How does the same picture that's also used on [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fig01.jpg) come into the claim? Is that another hint at the seriousness of this 'experiment'?